# alerts not showing up in my plunker for my angular md table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, plunker

- I am trying to display angular material table.
- so I debugged in the plunker.
- I gave alerts in different files of my code base
- but its not displaying the alerts when I run it in the plunker.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code and plunker below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/XLYLsuMd3I9ICuBgMeDH?p=preview

```or-tag-here
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    PlunkerMaterialModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
  ],

  declarations: [SelectFormExample],
  bootstrap: [SelectFormExample],
  providers: [AppState]
})
export class PlunkerAppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(PlunkerAppModule);
alert("I am here");
```

Comment: Changed the tags use "angular" for anything not 1.x, use "angularjs" for the 1.x branch to get the right eyes on it :)

Comment: Check the JS console (F12) to see errors, looks like it is having trouble loading http from https://unpkg.com/@angular/common@5.1.3/bundles/common.umd.js/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a version for `angular-in-memory-web-api` in `systemjs.config.js`

```
'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'https://unpkg.com/angular-in-memory-web-api@0.2.4/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
```

Without a version it uses the latest. I would find a more up to date plunker because the plunker is defaulting to the latest angular (v5.1.3) and it designed for ^4.0.0